# Learnyounode #9 - Issue getting my data to be outputted

Tags: node.js

I'm on question 9 of learnyounode and can't seem to figure out why my code is not outputting data. It's suppose to recieve 3 arguments, each containing data, and output them.

For the sake of brevity I only included the first one, as the next two are just repeats.

```
 var bl = require('bl');
var http = require('http')


var dataOne = http.get(process.argv[2], function(response){
    response.pipe(bl(function(err, data) {
        if (err) 
            return console.error(err)
        data = data.toString()
        return data
    }))
})
console.log(dataOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only include one argument with process.argv[2]

- process.argv[2] = is first argument you recieve
- process.argv[3] = is second argument you recieve
- process.argv[4] = is third argument you recieve

You can make an array that takes those 3 arguments and loop trough them. Hope this helps you a bit.